# What is the centralizer of $(123)(456)$ in $S_6$?

Tags: group-theory

Given that $\sigma = (123)(456)$. Compute $C_{S_6}(\sigma)$ (instead of writing out all the elements, write down the elements that generate the centralizer).

If $\sigma$ were an $m$-cycle we chould just write down: $C_{S_n}(\sigma)=\{\sigma^i \tau | 0 \leq i \leq m-1,\tau \in S_{n-m}\}$ and go from there. But we're dealing with two 3-cycles, so I'm struggling with how I can solve the systematically insteas of trying things out.

I first thought maybe the centralizer is simply $(123)(456)$ and $(123)(456)^2$, but there have to be $18$ elements and I can see that $(123)$ and $(456)$ have to be in the centralizer (their powers too?).

I know we're looking for elements $x$ in $S_6$ that give $x\sigma x^{-1}=\sigma$ and I know $x\sigma x^{-1}=(x(1)x(2)x(3))(x(1)x(2)x(3))$.

How should I tackle this problem? How do I find all the elements that generate the centralizer systematically?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\tau^{-1} \sigma \tau$ for some $\tau$.

Imagine $\tau(1) = 1$. Then $2 = \sigma(1) = \tau^{-1} \sigma \tau(1) = \tau^{-1}(2)$, so $\tau(2) = 2$, and similarly $\tau(3) = 3$.
So if $tau$ fixes $1$ then it also fixes $2$ and $3$; and by symmetry the following are equivalent:

- $\tau$ fixes $1$
- $\tau$ fixes $2$
- $\tau$ fixes $3$.

By symmetry, TFAE:

- $\tau$ fixes $4$
- $\tau$ fixes $5$
- $\tau$ fixes $6$.

Now suppose instead $\tau(1) = 2$. Then $2 = \sigma(1) = \tau^{-1} \sigma \tau(1) = \tau^{-1}(3)$, so $\tau(2) = 3$. Hence again TFAE:

- $\tau(1) = 2$
- $\tau(2) = 3$
- $\tau(3) = 1$

and TFAE:

- $\tau(4) = 5$
- $\tau(5) = 6$
- $\tau(6) = 4$

You can keep going through the options; once you've done this for all six possibilities, you get generators $(123), (456), (14)(25)(36)$.
You can check that these generate a subgroup of the right size.

Comment: It's so clear now, thanks! One last question about your last remark, is it safe to assume that products of distinct generating elements are also distinct? What I mean is, can we be sure that $(123)^x(456)^y \neq (123)^m ((14)(25)(36))^n \neq (456)^i((14)(25)(36))^j$ for some $x,y,m,n,i,j$? Is this true in general? 

Because then I can conclude that there are $2+2+1+2*2+2*2+2*2+1=18$ elements.

Comment: I see what you mean. Remember that $[(14)(25)(36)]^n$ is the identity if $n$ is even, so there are actually only two cases to check there.

Comment: I just wrote it all out. How did you get the generators? Did you check for each element if it could be generated by (a product of) one of those generators?